# NullPointerException When Trying to Create ImageAdapter

Tags: android

I am having some issues trying to create an ImageAdapter.  To be perfectly honest, I am not sure I am going about it the best way. I have 20 images in my `/assets` folder.  I have an array of those file names in `String` format.  I simply want to create a drop down (`Spinner`) in one of my dialog entries for people to select one of the images (not by name, but by the actual image).  I have provided all of the code related to what I am trying to do below.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Later on I will need to know which image was selected for a different `ListAdapter` I have to display the data.

EDIT: Fixed first bug.  Was using wrong findViewById.  It now crashes when i try pressing the drop down.  I'm not that familiar with `ArrayAdapter`  LogCat Below

```
package cs.ucsb.cs185.dimberman.lifeRPG;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    int layoutResourceId;
    public static final String CONTENT_URI = "content://cs.ucsb.cs185.dimberman.lifeRPG.assets.";

    public ImageAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, String[] icons) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, icons);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        ItemHolder holder = null;

        if(row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)parent.getContext()).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
            holder = new ItemHolder();
            holder.image = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.list_image);
            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ItemHolder)row.getTag();
        }

        final String s = getItem(position);
        holder.image.setImageURI(Uri.parse(CONTENT_URI + s));
        return row;
    }

    static class ItemHolder{
        ImageView image;
    }
}
```

Dialog Builder

```
private String [] icons = {
    "airplane.png", "bang.png", "drive_copy.png", "email.png", "heart.png", "kingOfWorld.png", 
    "leafy_outdoors.png", "miscellaneous_blob.png", "music.png", "outdoors.png", "paperclip.png",
    "pencil.png", "person.png", "pet.png", "radioactive.png", "shop.png", "star.png", "talk.png",
    "telephone.png", "thumbtack.png"
};

AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
alert.setTitle(R.string.add_activity);

final View v2 = this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.add_button_layout, null);

ImageAdapter adapter2 = new ImageAdapter(this, R.layout.image_drop_down_view, icons);

Spinner imageList = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.addActivityImageText);
imageList.setAdapter(adapter2);
// ...
```

XML for Simple Image item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/list_image"
        android:layout_width="50dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:contentDescription=""
        />


</LinearLayout>
```

XML For Alert Builder

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:padding="6dp" >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/row0ForDialog"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:weightSum="16">

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/addActivityImageLabel"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:text="@string/add_activity_image"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <Spinner
            android:id ="@+id/addActivityImageText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="11" 
            android:inputType="text" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

LogCat Crash

```
06-05 17:21:27.346: E/AndroidRuntime(1843): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-05 17:21:27.346: E/AndroidRuntime(1843): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
06-05 17:21:27.346: E/AndroidRuntime(1843):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3597)
06-05 17:21:27.346: E/AndroidRuntime(1843):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
06-05 17:21:27.346: E/AndroidRuntime(1843):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
06-05 17:21:27.346: E/AndroidRuntime(1843):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
06-05 17:21:27.346: E/AndroidRuntime(1843):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-05 17:21:27.346: E/AndroidRuntime(1843):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-05 17:21:27.346: E/AndroidRuntime(1843):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
06-05 17:21:27.346: E/AndroidRuntime(1843):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-05 17:21:27.346: E/AndroidRuntime(1843):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-05 17:21:27.346: E/AndroidRuntime(1843):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-05 17:21:27.346: E/AndroidRuntime(1843):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-05 17:21:27.346: E/AndroidRuntime(1843):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-05 17:21:27.346: E/AndroidRuntime(1843): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
06-05 17:21:27.346: E/AndroidRuntime(1843):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-05 17:21:27.346: E/AndroidRuntime(1843):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-05 17:21:27.346: E/AndroidRuntime(1843):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3592)
06-05 17:21:27.346: E/AndroidRuntime(1843):     ... 11 more
06-05 17:21:27.346: E/AndroidRuntime(1843): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-05 17:21:27.346: E/AndroidRuntime(1843):     at cs.ucsb.cs185.dimberman.lifeRPG.LifeRpgMain.listAdd(LifeRpgMain.java:159)
06-05 17:21:27.346: E/AndroidRuntime(1843):     ... 14 more
06-05 17:26:27.660: E/Trace(1875): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
```

EDIT: LogCat for second bug

```
06-05 17:35:35.719: E/AndroidRuntime(1949): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-05 17:35:35.719: E/AndroidRuntime(1949): java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
06-05 17:35:35.719: E/AndroidRuntime(1949):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:386)
06-05 17:35:35.719: E/AndroidRuntime(1949):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getDropDownView(ArrayAdapter.java:415)
06-05 17:35:35.719: E/AndroidRuntime(1949):     at android.widget.Spinner$DropDownAdapter.getDropDownView(Spinner.java:737)
06-05 17:35:35.719: E/AndroidRuntime(1949):     at android.widget.Spinner$DropDownAdapter.getView(Spinner.java:733)
06-05 17:35:35.719: E/AndroidRuntime(1949):     at android.widget.Spinner.measureContentWidth(Spinner.java:681)
06-05 17:35:35.719: E/AndroidRuntime(1949):     at android.widget.Spinner$DropdownPopup.show(Spinner.java:959)
06-05 17:35:35.719: E/AndroidRuntime(1949):     at android.widget.Spinner.performClick(Spinner.java:609)
06-05 17:35:35.719: E/AndroidRuntime(1949):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
06-05 17:35:35.719: E/AndroidRuntime(1949):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
06-05 17:35:35.719: E/AndroidRuntime(1949):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-05 17:35:35.719: E/AndroidRuntime(1949):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-05 17:35:35.719: E/AndroidRuntime(1949):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
06-05 17:35:35.719: E/AndroidRuntime(1949):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-05 17:35:35.719: E/AndroidRuntime(1949):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-05 17:35:35.719: E/AndroidRuntime(1949):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-05 17:35:35.719: E/AndroidRuntime(1949):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-05 17:35:35.719: E/AndroidRuntime(1949):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-05 17:35:35.719: E/AndroidRuntime(1949): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
06-05 17:35:35.719: E/AndroidRuntime(1949):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:379)
06-05 17:35:35.719: E/AndroidRuntime(1949):     ... 16 more
```

Comment: Where do you create `icons`? It's referenced when you create your adapter.

Comment: @KenWolf The icons is declared @ class level, I included it for now.

Comment: What's happening @ LifeRpgMain.java line 159? Seems to be the cause of the problem..

Comment: What is at line 159 of `LifeRpgMain`?

Comment: @MasterGberry you really should post the content of LifeRpgMain.java. All your errors are there, t'would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

if Spinner is Inside `DialogBox` layout (in `add_button_layout` ) then initialize it as:

```
Spinner imageList = (Spinner)v2. findViewById(R.id.addActivityImageText);
```

Comment: Ok. Got a bit further, whoops on forgetting to use v2.  Now it crashes when i try to click the Spinner.  I will post the new logcat.

Comment: @MasterGberry : ok then show Spinner onClick Listener code to get more help

Comment: I don't have one yet.  Maybe that's the problem xD

Comment: @MasterGberry : as in log `ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView` means you are passing layout id instead of TextView to ArrayAdapter

Comment: Why do I need a `TextView`?  Shouldn't it be an `ImageView`?

Comment: @MasterGberry : plz see http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/ tutorial for ArrayAdapter